# Extjs empty combo box value on expand click

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

i have created lazy loading combo box, which queries data by entered value. But i have issue when value is loaded from database and i click expand list button, it sends request with empty mask instead of taking value of combobox, it seems, that empty value is taken for some reason.

Here is my combo box :

```
editor : {
            xtype : 'lazycombo',
            minChars : 1,
            pageSize : 20,
            id : 'tax-code-combo',
            store : 'TaxCodesStore',
            triggerAction : 'all'
        }
```

and here is request params :

```
limit   20
mask    
organizationId  108
start   0
```

mask is empty instead of before set value.

Thanks for help

my store :

```
TaxCodesStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonStore, {
constructor : function(cfg) {
    cfg = cfg || {};
    TaxCodesStore.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
        storeId : 'TaxCodesStore',
        api : {
            read : 'taxCode/getPagedList'
        },
        root : 'data',
        baseParams : {
            organizationId : 0
        },
        idProperty : 'taxCode',
        fields : [ {
            mapping : 'taxCode',
            name : 'value'
        }, {
            mapping : 'taxCode',
            name : 'label'
        }, {
            name : 'orgId',
            type : 'int'
        }, {
            name : 'percentageRate',
            type : 'int'
        } ]
    }, cfg));
}
});

new TaxCodesStore();
```

**Update**

What i have found after investigation, that combo box method `getValue()` returns the value, but for some reason in is not set as store param mask on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the source, i have found there the problem was.

It was because of `triggerAction : 'all',` i removed it, and now my combo works perfect

Answer (score 1):

The "store" property mast be a reference on a such Ext.data.Store object:

```
store: Ext.create('TaxCodesStore', { ... });
```

Also need to configure "displayField" and "valueField" properties.

**UPD**:

```
    {
        xtype : 'lazycombo',
        minChars : 1,
        pageSize : 20,
        id : 'tax-code-combo',
        store : new TaxCodesStore(), // <---
        triggerAction : 'all',
        displayField: 'origId', // <---
        valueField: 'value' // <---
    }
```

Comment: i have added my store implementation

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it does not work for me, the same error i get

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/665G7/) will help you

HTML

```
<div id="cmb"></div>
```

Javascript

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['id', 'attr'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: {
                read: '/someurl'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                successProperty: 'success',
                totalProperty: 'total'
            }
        }
    });
    var cmb   = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        triggerAction: 'all',
        store: store,
        displayField: 'attr',
        valueField: 'id',
        queryMode: 'remote',
        listeners: {
            beforequery: function(){
                this.getStore().getProxy().extraParams.mask = this.getValue();
            }
        }
    });


    cmb.render('cmb');

})
```